# Image Resizing Not Happening

Tags: coldfusion, cfimage

Hey guys, I am trying to use a simple cfimage to resize a tmp image but its not working... am I doing it correctly?

```
<cfimage action="resize" height="300" source="#form.adminfileupload#" width="300" name="form.adminfileupload">
```

After it goes through that function I am trying to rename the tmp file. Is this the proper way to do this in ColdFusion?

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan to save the data to the filesystem, use the "destination" attribute instead of the "name" attribute.

I've not tried resizing directly from an upload.  You may need to use cffile to write a temp copy to a readable directory in order to provide a full filepath to cfimage.

Comment: Thanks, the destination was what it was and some variable naming conventions on my end.